# log log4j message in a seperate file in Grails

Tags: grails, logging

I am trying to log4j log (info and debug) in a separate file in /logs/mylog.log. I have created "logs/mylog.log under WEB-INF in my Grails project's folder structure. I also add appenders in Config.groovy. Below is my log4j entry inside log4j = {} in my config.groovy.

```
appenders {
    console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
    file name:'grailslog', file:'/logs/mylog.log', threshold:org.apache.log4j.Level.DEBUG, org.apache.log4j.Level.INFO
}

root { debug 'stdout', 'file'     }

error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
       'org.springframework',
       'org.hibernate',
       'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate',
       'com.test'

info   'com.test.nip'

//trace 'org.hibernate.type'
debug 'org.hibernate.SQL'

debug   'com.test.nip.pacs'

environments {
    production {
        debug   'com.test',
                'org.springframework.security'
    }
}
```

but here I am getting file not found error for '/logs/mylog.log' when I start my server.

Comment: You do not need to create a log file, the system can create it by itself.

Comment: So what will be the appender in log4j entry in my config.groovy. because i am getting below error.

Comment: Are you sure the running process has proper access to the folder?

Comment: yes access is already there. i am getting below error.

log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
Error |
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \logs\mylog.log (The system cannot find the path specified)

please help me on appender section.

Comment: create the folder /log/ under the sytem root - that is what you are using. Add proper access rights to the folder with chmod / chown.

Answer (score 1):

When you refer to the log file with the path `/logs/mylog.log` you are using an absolute path in the system your server is installed, it odes not mean it is under `WEB-INF` also putting a log file under `WEB-INF` is good idea because the file will be deleted as you deploy a new war.

**Possible Solution:**

1. Create the `/log` directory under the sytem root.
2. Make sure the server process has enough permission to create and write into the `/log` directory. If it does not, grant it permissions.

> How to add a rolling file appender?

```
rollingFile name: "file",
 maxFileSize: 5000000,
 file: "/log/mylog.log",
 threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.DEBUG
```

It is thoroughly documented in the [official doc](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.7/guide/conf.html).

Comment: hi Degen, thank u for your reply. it is working. I want to roll on max size basis. so can you please suggest me how can i add maxsize and rolling option in appender section.

Comment: @AnishRanjanDandapat please accept the above answer, since it solved the original problem.